# sessionStorage doesn't work when I try to retrieve an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

I am using an AJAX call to a web method to validate a user, and when the web call returns, I am trying to use this code to populate `sessionStorage` with an object so I can then access the user's information from other pages:

```
 success: function (r) {
                    var info = JSON.parse(r.d);
                    if (info.Reply == 'OK')
                    {
                        $('#signinForm').html("<p>You're logged in!</p>");
                        var MemberObject = { 'MemberName': $('#MemberName').val() };
                        sessionStorage.setItem('MemberObject', JSON.stringify(MemberObject));
                    }
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (r) {
                    alert(r.responseText);
                }
```

To test this, I added this block of code at the top of the page to replace the login dialogue with a welcome message for a logged-in user by retrieving the object I added to `sessionStorage`, but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        function isObject(val) {
            if (val === null) { return false; }
            return ((typeof val === 'function') || (typeof val === 'object'));
        }

        var mObj = sessionStorage.getItem('MemberObject');

        if (isObject(mObj))
        {
            var data = JSON.parse(mObj);
            $('signinForm').html("<p>Welcome, " + data.MemberName + "!</p>");
        }
```

Why doesn't `sessionStorage` working?

Comment: Won't `if (isObject(mObj))` always be `false`? The item you retrieve from storage will be a string.

Comment: Which code is getting executed first? From your code, I think  `var mObj = sessionStorage.getItem('MemberObject');` happens before the ajax call is made, where the value is set to session storage.

Comment: Or did you missed  # in `$('signinForm').html` ? And as @nnnnnn said, typeof val in this case is string.

Comment: The code to retrieve the object from session storage fires when the page is ready to test whether the user is already logged in.  If so then the code is supposed to display a welcome to the user instead of the login form.  The problem is that either nothing is getting written to sessionStorage or something is wrong with the code that is supposed to be retrieving from sessionStorage.  I only want the login form to show if the user is not already logged in.  If the page reloads, then it should check sessionStorage to determine if the current user is already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

As @nnnnnn said in comment, the `if (isObject(mObj))` condition will always return false. mObj is a string at that point in time. To resolve the problem, use `JSON.parse()` before the condition instead of after it, or use a different condition.